# How to extract ID document region of interest from image with OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to segment this image because I need only to obtain the document.

[image]

Applying some filters I got this result:

[image]

I am trying to get the outline of the white rectangle but I get this result:

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to do better?

this is my code :/

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('roberto.jpg')

image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('test', binary)
cv2.waitKey(0)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
idx = 0 
for cnt in contours:
    idx += 1
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    roi=binary[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,0,0),2)
cv2.imshow('img',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to obtain the `x,y,w,h` bounding rectangle coordinates using `cv2.boundingRect` then you can extract/save the ROI using Numpy slicing. Here's the result

[image]

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Get bounding box and extract ROI
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(thresh)
ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('ROI', ROI)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I thank you, apparently it was already close, however, the image I use when processing detects a larger box, you can see in the last image I shared, you would know how to improve the processing so that the rest of the white sheet is literally white hehe thanks!

Comment: Yes there are two methods: 1) Add a large blur (Gaussian or median blur) or 2) perform morph open after thresholding the image to remove small noise

Comment: I really appreciate the advice I will be testing and I will be updating the question. : P